# What is wrong with the returned tuple in this function?

Tags: ios, swift, tuples

This is a function that's supposed to return a tuple with types Int and Dictionary < String , AnyObject > However I keep getting this error "Tuple types '(Int, Dictionary < String, AnyObject > )' and '()' have a different number of elements (2 vs. 0)." It's weird because it seems like it's telling me that I'm returning the correct tuple, but I'm not sure why it says "(Tuple) and '()'" have different arguments.

```
    class func SomeFunc(param: String) -> (x: Int, y: Dictionary<String, AnyObject>){

    var request = HTTPTask()
    request.responseSerializer = JSONResponseSerializer()

    let params: Dictionary<String,AnyObject> = ["key": param]
    request.POST("http://mysite/url", parameters: params, success: {(response: HTTPResponse) in

        let dict = response.responseObject as Dictionary<String,AnyObject>
        let status:Int = 200
        return (status, dict) //Tuple types '(Int, Dictionary<String, AnyObject>)' and '()' have a different number of elements (2 vs. 0)


        },failure: {(error: NSError, response: HTTPResponse?) in

    })

}
```

Comment: Your `return` statement is returning from a closure, not from the function. You can't do what you are trying to do, because `POST` is asynchronous.

Answer (score 1):

Pass in a closure and execute it with the parameters needed:

```
func SomeFunc(param: String, withCompletion completion: (x: Int, y: Dictionary<String, AnyObject>) -> ()) {

    var request = HTTPTask()
    request.responseSerializer = JSONResponseSerializer()

    let params: Dictionary<String,AnyObject> = ["key": param]
    request.POST("http://mysite/url", parameters: params, success: {(response: HTTPResponse) in

        let dict = response.responseObject as Dictionary<String,AnyObject>
        let status:Int = 200
        completion(x: status,y: dict) //Tuple types '(Int, Dictionary<String, AnyObject>)' and '()' have a different number of elements (2 vs. 0)


        },failure: {(error: NSError, response: HTTPResponse?) in

    })
```